# How can I list all transitive dependencies of a multi-project build

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have a multi-project build with a lot of sub-projects.

How can I list all transitive dependencies of the multi-project build.

Ideally, this would be possible with some command line argument, i.e. without modifying any gradle files, and list a nice dependency tree on the command line.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html

Comment: @JBNizet: The documentation does not mention multi-project builds. If I use `gradle -q dependencies --configuration implementation` in root, my subproject dependencies are not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution which does modify the parent build.gradle (but minimally) is [from this blogpost](https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/gradle-tricks-display-dependencies-for-all-subprojects-in-multi-project-build/):

```
subprojects {
    task allDeps(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

Since my parent build.gradle has a `subprojects` section already, this is a one-liner. Furthermore, I can restrict the output by specifying a configuration. Hence this is an acceptable solution, so a command line option would be nicer.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-I` (or `--init-script`) at command line to specify an [Init Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#init_scripts)

You can then add whatever tasks etc you like in the init script without altering `build.gradle`